# How can I associate a service from another user's IBM Organization and Space?

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-studio

In Watson Studio, I can navigate to the Project Settings and add an associated service:

[image]

This appears to only let me add a service from the same IBM Cloud Organization and Space that the project belongs to.

Is it possible to add a service from another users IBM Cloud Organization and Space?  If so, how?  Note that I want to remain in my own IBM Cloud Organization and Space with the Watson Studio Project.

Comment: Technically you should switch to the IBM Cloud Account and Org  from top-right avatar(menu) that the service belongs to and then click add service and it will let you choose existing service from the Org/space that you switch to and once added.
Then you can switch back to the org/space that you were working in.
Can you explain why " Note that I want to remain in my own IBM Cloud Organization and Space with the Watson Studio Project.."

Comment: Sometimes you need to work with pre-existing services that have been deployed in someone else’s account (e.g. when two business partners are working together and one is responsible for the model building, the other for the model deployment).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully add services from different spaces in my account:

[image: one]

[image: one]

I was also able to successfully add a service from another account by using the menu in the upper right corner:

[image: two]

This way my Watson project has services from multiple accounts.

---

If you wish to remain in one account (with your business partner scenario), you could set up a permissioned space or org in an account and use that. Or you could have two accounts, and set up the permissions so you have access to one space in the second account which has the service that you want to use.

For new feature request or idea, you can submit a request here:

https://ibmcloud.ideas.aha.io/